# PyQt5 QTabs is this the only solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My GUI application needs to run multiple applications. Imagine a left (or top) menu resembling tabs, where user can select a tab and interact with application_x. It looks like QTab can do this. My questions are:

1. Is QTabs the only solution?
2. Can I put the tabs on the left (vs top), if so how?
3. Can all tabs (their respective application/processes) be running at the same time (concurrent) ? or only the exposed tab will be running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My Q1 was asking if QTabs is the only solution. Looks like actually it is called QTabWidget (but internet references have used different spellings). Q2 was can I put the tabs vertically on the left. Most examples are showing a horizontal layout (similar to chrome or ff tabs).

Comment: Q2: [QTabWidget.setTabPosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabPosition-prop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to use tabs to execute several tasks in the same application. Widgets are visual elements that do not implement logic to execute other tasks, they are used to obtain and display information from and to the user, respectively.

In the case of QTabWidget it is a widget that can contain several widgets and only show one widget.

With the above:

**1. Is QTabs the only solution?**

If your question is that to execute n tasks in the same application you must use tabs then the answer is no, it is not necessary since an application with only one window can execute n tasks.

**2. Can I put the tabs on the left (vs top), if so how?** Yes, You can place the tabs on the right side:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(tabPosition=QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
    for i in range(5):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.addTab(widget, "tab-{}".format(i))
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

**3. Can all tabs (their respective application/processes) be running at the same time (concurrent) ? or only the exposed tab will be running.**

As it indicates the amount of tasks executed does not depend on the tab. So you can always perform the tasks you want except for the limitations of your system (RAM, maximum number of threads, etc).

Comment: Follow up clarification please ....1) how do I change the tab text to be horizontal? 2) how do I change each tab's background color 3) what is the difference between QTabWidget and QTabBar

Comment: @user3912225 1 and 2 I have answered them previously so I recommend you do a search in OS. In the case of 3 a QTabBar is the widget that has only the tabs, instead a QTabWidget is a widget that has a QTabBar that allows you to select which widget will display, more details can be found in the docs. Finally I do not follow up on questions, and returned: do a search because much of what you are asking for has already been requested before and it is very possible that they already have solutions.